# How to get npm 5 to update lock file after adding new save-dev dependency?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

When running `npm install redux-observable --save-dev` with npm 5.0.3 in an existing project with an existing package.json, the lock file gets updated with the newly installed package (redux-observable in this case), but not any existing packages in the package.json. Running `npm install` to try and refresh or regenerate the lock file doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in npm 5.0.x:
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16893

To work around this issue, you *must* run `npm install` with no arguments in a freshly cloned/created repository *before* doing `npm install --save-dev package-name`. If you get the ordering wrong, you'll need to delete the lock file and then re-run `npm install` in order to get npm to add entries for the existing package.json to the lock file.